# How to multiply one NetCDF file to multiple NetCDF files

Tags: python, netcdf, loop, climate-data-operators, multiple

I have one NetCDF file ([region.nc](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f5MI6J58yaavKJ7LRy9tRyEIrevUtX-J/view?usp=sharing)) that I want to multiply to multiple NetCDF files such as the one in the picture using `-mul` from CDO.:

The output should be new NetCDF files resulting from the multiplication.
I am using Python, seeking a solution within the CDO operator:

```py
from cdo import *   
cdo = Cdo()
```

- This is the file for wsgmax.nc: [wsgmax.nc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LRfIapr6GvhRzP8rahF-TQ6sTg-dnot1/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102906691979981397504&rtpof=true&sd=true)
- This is region.nc content:

  [image]

Comment: @Felipe D. this is specifically what I want

Comment: netcdf files can have many, many variables in them.  What variable in `region.nc` do you want to multiply by which variables in `wsgmax.....nc`?  And are they all conformant?

Comment: @DaveX  I want to multiply the variable ['wsgmax10m'] in the wsgmax.nc file, this file is in hdf so it has other variables depending on it, which makes the multiplication get a lot of error regarding the other variables for example this is the wsgmax.nc structure (I edited the question to have the wsgmax.nc structure and also the region.nc structure. region.nc has (Band1(lat=1646, lon=1831)) variable